# Java:Interface instantiation with and without creating Object

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, interface, inner-classes

I have a bit Confusion in codes below.in the first code and interface is instantiated and object i is created:

```
Inter i=new Inter() {

            @Override
            public void work() {                                      //CODE:1
                System.out.println("work work work work work work");

            }
        }.work() ; //this won't worrk gives error:can't covert void to Inter
```

But if i instantiate without creating an object it all works fine:

```
 new Inter() {   //no object created 

            @Override
            public void work() {                                    //CODE:2
                System.out.println("CODE2: work work work work");

            }
        }.work();                 //this is printing in the console
```

can someone please tell me what is the reason?why code won't work if object i is created?

Comment: You can't assign a variable to a `void` method call. What are you confused about?

Comment: @kanwal check my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above implementation was not working because If you look closed the error.
Error was `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Inter`
You are calling method `work()` at the end so it treat as method call and your `work()` has return type `void`, so it throws exception. Remove chain call of `work()` It will work for you.

```
Inter i=new Inter() {

            @Override
            public void work() {                                      //CODE:1
                System.out.println("work work work work work work");

            }
        }.work() ; //this won't worrk gives error:can't covert void to Inter
```

If you change your above code with below one then it will work.

```
Inter i=new Inter() {

                @Override
                public void work() {                                      //CODE:1
                    System.out.println("work work work work work work");

                }
            };
i.work();
```